# Почему не работает JDBC драйвер?

Tags: java, android, mysql, jdbc

Вечерок всем! Пытаюсь подключиться к базе данных MYSQL при помощи JDBC драйвера. Использую Intelej Idea - все работает, копипастю ТОТ ЖЕ КОД в Android Studio - возникает ошибка при подключении. Прошу помощи!
После долгих манипуляций я пришел к такой ошибке:
"Could not create connection to database server"

[image: Код]
[image: Лог об ошибке]

Comment: Добавьте в блок `catch` строку `System.out.println(e.getMessage());` и покажите вывод ошибок. По текущим данным остается только гадать на кофейной гуще

Comment: Первое(и, наверное, единственное) что можно увидеть из скринов - в идее используется maven, а в Android Studio - gradle

Comment: Исправил! Спасибо за отклик. С нетерпением жду ответа!

Comment: Вероятнее всего неверный конфиг gradle, проверьте верно ли указаны зависимости.

Comment: нужен стектрейс ошибки

Answer (score 0):

JDBC из Android очень сложно заставить работать. Есть 2 причины:

1. Это [антипаттерн](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221620/android-jdbc-not-working-classnotfoundexception-on-driver/7221716#7221716) (для Android)
2. Многие JDBC драйвера (MySQL в их числе) используют вызовы нативных библиотек, которые не работают под Android